# SharePoint2010 /_vti_bin/listdata.svc

Tags: 2010, rest, search-results, listdata.svc

I was trying to mimic a search site via listdata.svc due to the incapability of OOTB Search Result webpart.

Is there'a way to utilize KQL or any other way to allow users to search for a sentence?

Here's my code:

```
var webServerRelativeUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
$.ajax({
    url: webServerRelativeUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Pages?$filter=(Title eq 'keyword')",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response.d.results[0].Title);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

However, users won't be able to get any results if they search for more than a word. Is there any syntax reference can help? Or there's a better way than "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SP2010 Search API is not exposed in the REST endpoints or in the javascript CSOM but you can get to it via SPServices.  Take a look at this blog post, it should give you what you need:

http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/example-of-using-the-spservices-search-web-service/

The search results come back in XML so you'll need to do some XML traversal in your code to pull out the title of the document/page/listItem in your searchResults.